# If statement with parenthesis in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with quite a simple if statement that I am using in a javascript file. See an example of it below.

I was wondering if it reads/acts like the following:

```
if (var A === var B) && 
(var C truthy && (var C !== var D))

OR

(var A === var B) && 
(typeof var C ==='undefined' && (var C !== var D))
```

**Below the statement as it is in my code:**

```
if ((A === B) && (C && (C !== D) || typeof C ==='undefined' && (C !== D))) {
alert ('through'); }
```

Is this the if statement correct and is this an optiomal way of coding it?

Comment: The boolean expression `c` doesn't just check whether or not it's undefined, it just checks whether it's truthy

Comment: Truthy as in declared?

Comment: No, [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: No, `truthy` as in has a value that is not `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, or `NaN` (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: I would take a step back and analyse what you intend to do. There will be simplicity here, if not, nest it. You write code for other people (including yourself) so write for clarity and simplicity

Comment: You cannot use `var` inside a condition. It is reserved for defining variables.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. `A` is not the same variable as `a`.

Comment: @MarkRobson I was trying to elaborate what I am trying to do in the first piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, then you are asking about boolean logic in general, not specifically JavaScript.

You have this expression, which has certain boolean sub-expressions, which we could give a name as follows:

```
   (A === B) && (C && (C !== D) || typeof C ==='undefined' && (C !== D))
// ----X----    (------Y-------    ----------------Z-------------------)
```

So the boolean expression has this pattern:

```
X && (Y || Z)
```

According to the [distributive law in boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Definition) this is equivalent to:

```
(X && Y) || (X && Z)
```

... which is really what you seemed to be asking. The parentheses in this last expression are optional, as the logical AND operator has higher precedence than the logical OR operator.

So your interpretation correctly reflects the code.

Your second question was:

> Is this ... `if` statement ... an optimal way of coding it?

Because `C !== D` occurs in two places, the expression is equivalent to the following expression, again applying the distributive law:

```
   A === B && C !== D && (C || typeof C === 'undefined')
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a million. This is quite similar to what @Cheloide is suggestion correct? Also, why you need the value of the variables? These are not static. All i know is that I need the logic that I mentioned in my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed I see Cheloide comes to the same simplified expression (with a different order, but that is equivalent by boolean algebra laws). I don't need the value of the variables. I did not understand from your question that the logic you mentioned in the first part of the question was actually what you *wanted* it to mean. So in that case all is good ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`if (var A === var B) && (var c truthy && (var c !== var d))`

translates to

```
a === b && ( c && c !== d )
```

and `(var A === var B) && (typeof var c ==='undefined' && (var c !== var d))` translates to

```
a === b && ( typeof(c) === 'undefined' && c !== d )
```

You can merge the statements like this

```
if( a === b && ( c  || typeof(c) === 'undefined' ) && c !== d )
    alert ('through');
```

Comment: Thanks, thats better i guess yes. Check if c is truthy OR type is undefined and then match it. However the parenthesis are not valid in your code correct?

Comment: I just fixed the parenthesis.

Answer (score -3):

```
if ((a === b) && (c && (c !== b)
```

here the last "b" should be a "d". Otherwise if(c) and if(typeof c === 'undefined') is the same

Comment: What if `c = false`?

Comment: `if(c)` and `if(typeof c === 'undefined')` is never the same

Comment: Sorry, meant var `d` there